# What does 元金成長型 mean in this sentence

Tags: words, meaning, kanji

> お預け入れいただく明細は、すべて「元金成長型」のお取り扱いとなります。

what does 元金成長型 mean in the above sentence.

Comment: It doesn't look like a common word. Have you searched for its meaning?

Comment: Yes I tried searching it. But I think it is related to interest rates.

Comment: I wonder if it's a standard term, but as far as I get from Google, it seemingly refers to a type of time (fixed) deposit that automatically carries over all the principal and interest into the next round. Maybe you should ask your bank or advisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a term invented by the financial industry. 元金 means the capital (as opposed to the interest), and 成長型 means the type of financial product is "growth". I.e. a financial product that "attempts to grow your capital".

A similar term is 元金確保型 which normally means it's a more conservative asset allocation.

(This is completely unrelated from the language perspective but be wary of these mutual funds Japanese banks push on you, almost all of them are a terrible deal).